# Assertions with array -js , chai

Tags: javascript, chai

I read this http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

and tried to make some code with array..I need to make sure that one part of my array is including ...

```
 expect(LoginPage.listOfItems(ITEM1).to.be.an("array")).that.include(ITEM1);
```

but I got
Cannot read property 'be' of undefined

when I make console.log

```
console.log(LoginPage.listOfItems(ITEM1).getText());
```

I can get proper value showed...
what i made wrong?:(

Answer (score 0):

You have the brackets at the wrong place.

```
expect(LoginPage.listOfItems(ITEM1)).to.be.an("array").that.include(ITEM1);
```

You can refer the docs [here](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

Comment: thanks but did not helped:( expect(...) is not a function..and when I changed sth(did nod use Item1 in first expect) I got expected { Object (state, sessionId, ...) } to be an array